# Can't get objects in the order they where created via Parse.com with createdAt - Swift 1.2 - Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

My problem is that messages are not showed in the right order, and on my device/simulator in the timeline tableView I find showed my actual (on Mac/device) date and time in each cell, but I'd like to get messages in the order they where created by values in the "createdat" column on the server.

Don't know how `orderByAscending` function should be used, so I'm not using it at the moment.

As you can see, dates do not match, and messages are in wrong order, as never reversed them

[image]
[image]

Some info on the app:

From a `prepareForSegue` in `ChannelsTVC`, I pick a keyword from an array, and "send" it to `MessagesTimelineTVC` via `filterToParse` variable, in order to select only keyword-related messages in "Messages" class.

In the `PFQuery` `//MARK: Retrive Date from Parse 1/3` I ask both for text messages and they date separately, put them in two different arrays, reverse them then finally show them in the tableView.

Thanks in advance.

In `MessagesTimelineTVC` `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I have:

```
//MARK: Retrive Date from Parse 3/3
        var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"
        var useDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self.messageDateArray[indexPath.row])
        cell.dateMessageLabel.text = useDate
```

The function I retrive data via PFQuery is in `viewDidAppear` in `MessagesTimelineTVC`:

```
func loadData() {



timelineData.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)          //erase previus contents
println("timelineData cleared")


//MARK: Starts the PFQuery
var findTimeLineDataQuery = PFQuery(className: "Messages")

findTimeLineDataQuery.whereKey("channel", containsString: FilterToParse) //MARK: - filter for Parse - should filter parse query

findTimeLineDataQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
    (objects : [AnyObject]?, error : NSError?) -> Void in

    if error == nil {
        for singleObject in objects! {
            if let stringData = singleObject["message"] as? String {
                self.timelineData.append(stringData)

                //MARK: Retrive Date from Parse 1/3
                if let messageDate = singleObject.createdAt {
                    self.messageDateArray.append(messageDate!)
                    println("retrived date from Parse is: *\(messageDate!)*")
                }
            }
        }

        let reversedArray : Array = self.timelineData.reverse()  //MARK: Always Remember! (reverse array order)
        self.timelineData = reversedArray as Array

        //MARK: Retrive Date from Parse 2/3
        let reversedMessageDateArray : Array = self.messageDateArray.reverse()  //MARK: Always Remember! (reverse array order)
        self.messageDateArray = reversedMessageDateArray as Array


        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `orderByAscending` or `orderByDescending` within the query variable such as :

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "name")
query.orderByAscending("createdAt")
//You can use the functions like that
```

In your case :

```
findTimeLineDataQuery.orderByAscending("createdAt")
```

It is the easiest way.

Comment: it seems to work! I put it here: `var findTimeLineDataQuery = PFQuery(className: "Messages")
        
        findTimeLineDataQuery.whereKey("channel", containsString: filterToParse)
        findTimeLineDataQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt")` so do you think I did well in `//MARK: Retrive Date from Parse 3/3
` even if hours are different from server?

Comment: For the hours, Parse changes your time to UTC. This is why.